# Show data while it's being sent to the backend

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to solve a user experience problem.

I'm building a chatting app using Ionic, Angular, and Firebase.

The problem I'm having is that when a user sends a message, the message only appears once it's *successfully* sent to the server.

So, what this means is that if you're on a slow connection, you won't be able to type the next message until the first message is successfully sent.

Here is my simplified HTML:

```
//For viewing messages
<div *ngFor="let message of messageFeed; let in = index">
  <div class="messageCont">
    <div class="messageBubble"
      [ngClass]="{'fromMe': message.uid == userData.uid, 'fromYou': message.uid != userData.uid}">
        {{message.text}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

//For sending messages
<div>
<ion-item>
  <ion-textarea id="replyTextarea" [(ngModel)]="messageText" autocorrect="on" maxlength="450" (input)='charCount($event.target, false)' placeholder="Write something nice..."></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
<button type="button" id="postReplyBtn" (tap)="sendMessage()" class="glowBtn white" ion-button outline>Send</button>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
sendMessage() {
    let date = new Date().getTime();
    let messageKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
    let messageData = {
      text: this.msg,
      uid: this.userData.uid,
      recipient: this.recipient,
      created: date,
      messageId: messageKey,
    };
    this.database.list('threads/' + this.threadId + '/messages').set(messageKey, messageData).then(() => {
      console.log("Message Sent!")
      this.messageText = "";
      this.content.scrollToBottom(100);
      this.messageFeed.push(messageData)
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

So, as you can see `messageText` clears when the message is sent successfully, and `messageFeed` gets a new item *only* when the message is sent successfully.

But what I want is that `messageFeed` gets an item as soon as "Send" is clicked, and then that item needs to be removed when it is *actually* sent. Because in the `ngOnInit()` I have this code:

```
getChatMsg() {
    this.getChat = this.database.database.ref('/threads/' + this.threadId + '/messages/')
      .orderByChild('created')
      .limitToLast(25);
      this.getChat.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
this.messageFeed.push(snapshot.val());

});
}
```

which loads the newest message.

Does this make sense? How can I show the message in `messageFeed` while it's still sending so that the user can send as many messages as they want while the server is receiving them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set()` operation is completed asynchronously already, but its `then()` callback is only invoked once completion is confirmed from the server. Since you want to clear the input sooner then that, you should move that code out of the `then()` callback.

So something like:

```
this.database.list('threads/' + this.threadId + '/messages').set(messageKey, messageData).then(() => {
  console.log("Message committed on server")
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error)
});
console.log("Message Sent!")
this.messageText = "";
this.content.scrollToBottom(100);
this.messageFeed.push(messageData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could push that msg to messageFeed, and made use of [webWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) to work with low or offline mode. Once the webWorker could send the data sucessfully, then append some icon (double check) to indicate that message was send.